# AWS EC2 spot instance shutdown behavior from PHP SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have scripts that automate Amazon EC2 spot instance requests, written using Amazon PHP SDK. I also want to terminate instances when they shut down (as opposed to default "stop" action); I know I need to set `InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior` parameter.

However, it is not available in the PHP SDK when creating a spot request. Interestingly, it is available in a `runInstances` call... I could probably use `modifyInstanceAttribute`, but at the time of spot request creation there is no instance ID as one hasn't yet been started, so I would have to wait some time until request is completed, iterate through all running instances (possibly thousands) and set the parameter - but while I do that the instance itself may already have executed shutdown command, ending up in a stopped state because of the default behavior.

Is there any other way to set default shutdown behavior when creating spot requests?

Answer (score 1):

The only shutdown behavior of a spot-instance is termination.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere in AWS docs? I could not find any reference.